# How to add a new row at the begin of a vector of vectors

Tags: c++, vector

I would like to add a new row at the begin of a vector of vectors. I have a 3x3 vector and I want a 4x3 . This is my code:

```
typedef vector<int> state;
typedef vector<vector<int> > board;

int val;
string s;

while (getline (in, s)) {
    istringstream iss (s);

    while (iss >> val)
        boards.push_back(val);
}

sizeb = boards.front();

for (auto it = boards.cbegin()+1; it <= boards.cbegin()+pow(sizeb, 2); ++it)
    sstart.push_back(*it);

start.resize(sizeb); 

for (int i = 0; i < sizeb; ++i)
    start[i].resize(sizeb);

for (int i = 0; i < sizeb; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < sizeb; j++)
        start[i][j] = sstart[(i * sizeb) + j];
```

When I try to do sizeb+1 it adds a new row but also a new column.

Could you help me?

Comment: Why not use `vector.insert()` to insert your new row?

Comment: You have a naked `vector<int>` in the middle of your code. What's that about? Clearly it doesn't compile.

Comment: Yeah, it was a mistake. Just ignore it hahaha

Comment: You literally wrote code to add a new column to each row. Not sure what you expected.

Answer (score 0):

> How to add a new row at the begin of a vector of vectors

You can do that with `std::vector::insert`.

> When I try to do sizeb+1 it adds a new row but also a new column.

That's because you resize every row using a loop:

```
// I'm assuming that start is the vector of vectors

start.resize(sizeb); // this changes the number of rows

for (int i = 0; i < sizeb; ++i)
    start[i].resize(sizeb); // these change the number of columns in each row
```

Comment: I receive a "error: no viable overloaded '='" error.

Comment: @Elena OK. There is something wrong with your code.

Comment: @Elena as the error states, there is no viable overloaded '='.

Comment: I'm not pretending to be rude, but I can read the error in the compiler by myself.